# WYSIWYG editor rendering different between Firefox and IE7

Tags: javascript, firefox, internet-explorer-7

I have embedded openwysiwyg editor in web application. The things work perfectly fine in Firefox. So the exact scene is I select a drop-down option for email and text area shows up. This text area is replaced by openwysiwyg editor for email formatting. So this looks perfect in Firefox, but doesn't work correctly in Internet Explorer 7. In IE7, the editor shows up even before I select drop-down option. How does IE7 render JavaScript differently from Firefox?

Comment: Which wysiwig editor are you using ? Where's the code actually triggering the rendering of the editor ?

Comment: Martijn - I am using open source Openwysiwyg editor. Before loading of the page, I add editor script in my header of the page.

Comment: But this particular editor works only if you have textarea of particular ID loaded on page.

Comment: I am using this one http://www.openwebware.com/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest dropping that editor, which doesn't support Google Chrome (v.14.0.835.202 as of this writing), for a more popular open-source WYSIWYG editor called [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/).

TinyMCE will most likely give your users a more [consistent browser experience](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Browser_compatiblity), and I've personally used this in my projects with great success.

You only have to include the plugins you need, which can make it much more simplified if you want.